# PC black screen on boot

Tags: boot, display

When I start my pc the screen stays black. There are no beeps.

I have tested the screen with my laptop so the screen and cable both work.
I have also tried taking out the GPU and plugging the cable directly into the motherboard but that didn't change anything.
Clearing the CMOS also didn't work.

I'm not sure if it's related but the HDD activity light keeps blinking the whole time when the pc is on.

It just started happening today, I haven't changed anything so at the moment I have no idea what could be causing the issue.

Comment: @TiO thanks! I'll try replacing the PSU and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform Automatic Repair in Windows recovery. Download an ISO in DVD or USB.
a) After you boot your computer using Windows DVD or System Repair Disc, a black screen appears with gray text "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD". Press any key.
b) Select the correct time and Keyboard type.
c) Click Repair your computer in the lower left corner.
d) Select Troubleshoot from Choose an option screen.
e) Click advanced options in Troubleshoot screen.
f) Select Automatic repair.

Best regards,
Yilia

---

If you cannot see the logo of PC brand, this is likely due to a hardware issue. Please check your hardware and disconnect or replace legacy hardware.

Comment: When I boot with the cd the screen stays black and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your system. This way sometimes work in order to get rid of unnecessary interruptions which appears on Windows OS.